# how to set any html element value using web Browser in vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net

I want to fill web form automatically and then login from vb.net program .I am using web browser control to navigate to specific url but i am not to set textbox values.Here is my code

```
      Dim theButton As HtmlElement
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = Me.WebBrowser1.Document
    Try
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.facebook.com", Nothing, Nothing, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1468.0 Safari/537.36")
        doc.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value", "arorabharat56@gmail.com")
        ' Link the ID from the web form to the Button var
        theButton = doc.GetElementById("u_0_4")

        ' Now do the actual click.
        theButton.InvokeMember("click")

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show("hello")

    End Try
```